# Use of *(char *) in C++

Tags: c++

I don't understand what using this syntax is for: `*(char *)`. What does it do and can it be used with other data types like `int`?

```
void function(int a)
{
    *(char*)(0x12345 + (0x3980 * a)) = 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: Where did you see this used?

Comment: Makes much more sense to me now.

Comment: This is called a "C-style" cast and its use is discouraged in c++.  C++ provides various other casts which clarify intent and restrict type conversions among what's appropriate for various use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*(char *)hoge` means that interpret `hoge` as a pointer for `char` and read the data on where `hoge` points at.

It can be used with other data types like `int`.

One usage example: comparison function for `qsort`

```
int cmp(const void *x, const void *y) {
    int a = *(int *)x;
    int b = *(int *)y;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this method is the 'C' way of casting. In C++ you would use reinterpret_cast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got your example from, but it doesn't make sense to me for some reason. Anyway, when you use the character "*" before something like (char*), what is happening is you're telling the compiler to cast the value computed between those parentheses (0x12345 + (0x3980 * a)) into a pointer to char, and then change the value store in that location on the memory to be 0xFF.
In other words, what just happened is you grabbed a random location on the memory, and you told the compiler to act like that location contain a char "*(char*)", and store my value "0xFF" there.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a real example, I just made it up based on a real one to make it cleaner. But I sort of understand what you're getting at.

Comment: Oh I see. Well yea it's so powerful, and yet so dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been awnsered already but here is a "real world" example where this kind of syntax is used.

In (low-level) embedded software developement you often have to interface with a mcu's hardware peripheripherals. These perhipherals are controlled by registers which are mapped to fixed memory addresses.

When an mcu has multiple of the same peripherals (ie. 3 ADC's) it'll usually have 3 equal register sets mapped right after each other.

When interfacing you want to work with the addresses directly but add an abstraction. A simple API for control may looks like this:

.H file

```
/* Header file, defines addresses for specific chip*/

#define ADC_BASE_ADDRESS        0x00001000  /* Start address of first register of ADC0 */
#define SIZEOF_ADC_REGISTERS    0x00000020  /* Size of all ADC0 registers */

#define ADC_REG_CFG_OFFSET      0x00    /* ADC Config register offset */
#define ADC_REG_BLA_BLA_OFFSET  0x04    /* ADC Config register offset */
/* etc, etc, etc*/

#define ADC_CFG_ENABLE          0x01    /* Enable command */
```

.C file

```
#include "chip.h"

void adc_enable(int adc){
    *(uint32_t *)(ADC_BASE_ADDRESS + ADC_REG_CFG_OFFSET + (adc * SIZEOF_ADC_REGISTERS)) = ADC_CFG_ENABLE;
}

/* Calling code */
adc_enable(0);
adc_enable(3);
```

Do note, as mentioned this is typically done in C, not so much in C++.